# Corrupted pdf decoded and sent over Java server socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, pdf, networking

I have a program that decodes a pdf and sends it over a socket. I viewed a lot of code on stack overflow but haven't been able to find something that fixes the issue. The android client reads text, converts it to byte code and writes a file to the cache that is supposed to be loaded by a pdfViewer. Any testing on the pdf viewer works, as well as messages that are communicated to the client, but when the file is sent over via socket, the pdf is corrupted. The file is in fact created, and will return an error that the pdf is empty if no bytes are written to it. I excluded error catching and other information because the rest of the code is unrelated:

Server:

```
File f = new File(PATH_TO_PDF);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
byte[] pdf = new byte[(int)(f.length())];

int a;
int count = 0;
while ((a=is.read())!= -1){
       pdf[count] = (byte)a;
       count++;
       }

is.close();
String result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < pdf.length; i++) {
     returnMessage.append(pdf[i]);
     }

OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
bw.write(returnMessage + "\n");
System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+ returnMessage);
bw.flush();

//rest is closing socket stuff
```

Client:

```
 InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
 String message = br.readLine();
 s.close();

 byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();

 File someFile = new File(getCacheDir() + "/file.pdf");
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
 fos.write(bytes);
 fos.flush();
 fos.close();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You use `Writer` and `Reader` classes. This means you handle the data as text. This alone suffices to damage binary data, e.g. pdf files. Furthermore you don't show the type of `returnMessage`. Whether your operations with it make sense, therefore, is unclear. Also you implicitly assume that a pdf file does not contain a byte that can be interpreted as line separator when you try to read it using a single `readLine()`...

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it to work based on your advice! Will post an edit showing new code

Comment: Stack overflow is a q&a style site. Thus, the solution should be put into an answer post to your question and then you should accept it. Do you want to make that an answer or shall I?

Comment: You can go ahead and do it so I can give you credit for it, then I will remove the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Writer` and `Reader` classes and text line oriented methods:

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
bw.write(returnMessage + "\n");
```

and

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String message = br.readLine();
byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
```

This means you handle the data as text. This alone suffices to damage binary data, e.g. pdf files.

*Whenever you treat binary data as text, the data bytes are assumed to be text encoded according to some character encoding, e.g. Latin-1 or UTF-8. But not all byte sequences can properly be transformed to text, there are byte sequences for which there is no text which would encode to those sequences, in particular according to UTF-8. Such byte sequences then usually are transformed to a [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character), so the original sequences are lost in translation. When the string is treated as byte array again, instead of those sequences you get the character code of the replacement character, and the file is damaged.*

Furthermore, you most likely cut off the read data early.

*`BufferedReader.readLine()` only reads characters up to the next character that can be interpreted as line separator. As bytes representing line separators according to the underlying encoding can occur in arbitrary positions in binary files, `readLine()` most likely did not even read the whole (already damaged) PDF document.*

---

Based on these hints you changed your code so that it does not treat the PDF as text:

Server:

```
File f = new File("Path_to_PDF");
byte[] pdf = new byte [(int)f.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
bis.read(pdf,0,pdf.length);
OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
os.write(pdf, 0, pdf.length);
os.flush();
```

Client:

```
int FILE_SIZE = 60000000; //just a large size
int current = 0;
byte[] pdf = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
File someFile = new File(getCacheDir() + "/file.pdf");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
int bytesRead = 0;
int b;
while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
   bos.write(b);
   bytesRead++;
}
bos.flush();
bos.close();
fos.close();
```

With these changes the code works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!